# pandas problem in calling rolling window and lambda function

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with the following set of columns (from the df.columns function):

```
Index(['open', 'high', 'low', 'close'], dtype='object')
```

I am trying to compute loss functions (future in time) with this code

```
    rolling_loss = lambda x: (x["high"].max() - x["close"].iloc[0])
    indexer = pd.api.indexers.FixedForwardWindowIndexer(window_size=3)
    df["rolling_loss"] = df.rolling(window=indexer, min_periods=1).apply(rolling_loss)
```

The intent is to calculate the difference between max high value in the next 3 days and today's close value within the 3 day window

Two asks: Yes. I need help to resolve the error as everything seesm correct in my "eyes". Seond ask is how do you debug problems like this - just experience? Is there something I am not doing.

TIA

edit: The below works without errors. but think the lambda is elegant.
Any suggestions

````
  rolling_loss = lambda x: (x["high"].max() - x["close"].iloc[0])
    indexer = pd.api.indexers.FixedForwardWindowIndexer(window_size=3)
    # df["rolling_loss"] = df.rolling(window=indexer, min_periods=1).apply(rolling_loss)

    df["roll_3_max"] = df["high"].rolling(window=indexer, min_periods=1).max()
    df["roll_3_min"] = df["low"].rolling(window=indexer, min_periods=1).min()
    df["roll_3_loss_up"] = df["roll_3_max"] - df["close"]
    df["roll_3_loss_dn"] = df["roll_3_min"] - df["close"]
    pp(df.head(10))

```
````